# What kind of animal is Gru's pet Kyle?

Tags: animals, despicable-me

In the movies Despicable Me 1 and 2, Gru has a pet with sharp teeth and small body. His pee makes the shrub dead! The creature looks like a skunk to me but when Lucy scans him, its species is "UNKNOWN".

**Do we have any knowledge of what that creature really is?**

[image]

Comment: I always thought it to be a genetically altered dog...

Comment: “The creature looks like a skunk to me” — what the hell kinda [skunks](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=skunk&espv=2&biw=1276&bih=682&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI3_2BuqS6xwIVBNYaCh3QBgAH) have you seen??

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's furry, with a big mouth!!!

Comment: [Kangaroo rat](http://wiki.ggc.edu/wiki/Kangaroo_rats_(Dipodomys_sp.):_kings_of_water_conservation) kidneys, possibly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wikipedia lists him in a [list of fictional **dogs** in animation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_dogs_in_animation), which supports the general idea that it's a genetically modified dog. (His name is Kyle; that's what he's listed under in the Wiki article.)

In both films, Gru refers to Kyle as his “dog” when people ask what Kyle is:

- In *DM*, when Gru is showing the girls around the house, Margo ask what Kyle is. Gru says that he’s his “dog”, which gets a growl from Kyle. However, when asked what sort of dog Kyle is, he says, “He’s a… I don’t know.”
- In *DM2*, Gru makes pointed reference to that fact that he’s putting a “dog” in his neighbour’s backyard.

Answer (score -1):

[image] a

He's most likely a altered Brussels Griffin. Lol.

Comment: Welcome to SFF. Can you edit your answer to explain why you think that? Supporting details would be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Based on looks and Gru's bizarre collection, Kyle must be a mythical dog Chupacabra. Bluish, spiky sharp spines, few threads of fur, very pronounce fangs something that crosses a dragon with canine. Please take note that a Chupacabra legends denotes that when disturbed it leaves a leave a sulfur stench, this explains Kyle's effect on plants when it pees.

Gru simplified it as of a "dog" but actually confuses him too, Kyle was not identified in DM 2 because Lucy's data base presumably identifies only animals with known existing DNA thus a mythical undocumented species like a cryptid chupacabra fit Kyle to a T is not on the list

[image: chupacabra]